# Как первести значение даты в милисекундах в формат datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

В приходящих данных дата с милисекундами приходит в таком формате:

```
1616576493335
```

при переводе выдает это:

```
1970-01-01 00:26:56.483196596
```

Пытался использовать другие флаги, но их вообще не принимает. Вариант выше оказался более адекватный в плане формата, но вот год и дату он не отпределил.

Код:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

timezone = pytz.timezone("Etc/UTC")
utc_from = datetime(2021, 3, 23, tzinfo=timezone)
#Создает новый файл , если он есть то просто подключается
base = sqlite3.connect('new_base.db')
#Класс для создания, чтения, изменения таблиц
cur = base.cursor()
# получение данных
read_db = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM data_eurusd').fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(read_db)
#d = pd.read_sql("select * from data", db_conn)
#удаляяем ненужные столбцы
del df[1]
del df[4]
del df[6]
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0], unit='ns')
print(df.head(300000))
```

Подскажите, как исправить на нужный формат?

Сами данные были записаны 23.03.2021.

Answer (score 4):

У вас `timestamp` в миллисекундах, его и нужно использовать в качестве параметра `unit`:

```
In [34]: pd.to_datetime([1616576493335], unit="ms")
Out[34]: DatetimeIndex(['2021-03-24 09:01:33.335000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: огромное спасибо)

Comment: @xxxHEKETOSxxx, всегда пожалуйста)

Comment: увидел свою ошибку...

Comment: @xxxHEKETOSxxx Отметьте специальной галочкой этот ответ, чтобы ваш вопрос не числился на сайте как не получивший адекватного ответа